# How can I use my touchpad while typing in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, touchpad

In previous versions the answers have all been different, but none of them seem to work in the latest version of Ubuntu. I have a Dell Latitude E4310 with its pre-installed touchpad.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Gnome3 disables the touchpad while typing by default. You can disable that feature using the gnome tweak tool.

The entry for the touchpad is under *Keyboard & Mouse* in the tool.

To get the tool either install it via `sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool` in the terminal or search for `Gnome Tweaks` in the Ubuntu software store.

Answer (score 10):

Open a terminal and type this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad "disable-while-typing" false
```

To disable again type:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad "disable-while-typing" true
```

If you like a short form (alias), I suggest the following. The next 3 lines will add an alias your `.bashrc`. Copy this and add these into your terminal.

```
echo "# Alias for en-/disabeling the Touchpad 
echo "alias dit=\"gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad "disable-while-typing" true\"" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "alias ent=\"gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad "disable-while-typing" false\"" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Verify that the 3 lines are written into your .bashrc by

```
tail ~/.bashrc
```

Now resource your `.bashrc` by

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Now by typing

```
dit
```

you will disable your touchpad while typing,

```
ent
```

will enable your touchpad while writing.

Comment: It should read "To enable again type:", not disable.